# Note-Taking App: expand/collapse paragraphs/subparagraphs for outlining notes (Android)

Tags: android, text-editor, note-taking

I'm looking for a note-taking application that has a feature to expand/collapse paragraphs/sub-paragraphs via indentation.

This helps a lot for outlining and making the structure of my notes more organized/simple and accessible.

OneNote for desktop provides this [feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-outline-to-structure-notes-ae4c3783-422c-48b4-bc3a-a3a3fd856518), but unfortunately it doesn't provide it for Android.

Answer (score 1):

[Qrgzly](http://www.orgzly.com/) has the text folding feature. but it's mostly an outliner. On Linux the Org mode on which it works on is more suitable for longer text passages.

[workflowy](https://workflowy.com/) is another alternative.